# React onkeypress event to run a function

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-events, onkeypress

I'm new at react & coding.
I want to run a function if space & up arrow pressed. i want to run my jump() function

```
const jump = () => {
    if (onJump == false){
        $("#dino").animate({top:'-=60%'}, 300);
        $("#dino").animate({top:'+=60%'}, 300);
        onJump=true;
        setTimeout(function() {
          onJump=false;
        },600)
    }
}
```

i already try several codes but none of them are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const handlePress = e => {
 if(e.key === 'Enter') { 
  jump()
 }
}

<button onKeyPress={handlePress}>Press Enter</button>
```

See key codes https://keycode.info/

Html elements `div, h1, p, nav, ...` don't receive events like `keypress, focus, blur, ...` by default. You can enable it specifying `tabindex`:

```
<div tabIndex={-1} onKeyPress={...}></div> // better to use <= 0
```

The above `handleFunction` runs if your cursor is over that element but if you want it to fire independent to cursors position, you should  add eventlistener to window:

```
useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(e.key === 'Enter'){
   console.log('You pressed Enter')
  }
 })
})
```

---

#### EDIT:

use `keydown` event otherwise arrow keys don't work

---

#### EDIT 2:

the best practice for performance is to remove the event listener on un-mount:

```
useEffect(() => {
 const onKeyDown = (e) => {
  if(e.key === 'Enter'){
   console.log('You pressed Enter')
  }
 }

 window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
 return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
},[])
```

Comment: why when i press the key, the function will run twice?

Comment: @Green_Sand did you wrap the code inside the useEffect()?   `useEffect(() => { window.addEventListener(...) }, [])`

Comment: @Green_Sand Take a look, i edited my answer

Comment: thank you bro, i didn't use useEffect before

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to focus on any element and want to listen to keyboard events, you need to add listener to the window object. Here is the solution for `spacebar` key be pressed down and key up event of `up` key

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function KeyUpHandler() {

    const keysPressedDown = useRef({});

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("keydown",
            (event) => {
                // space
                if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                    keysPressedDown.current[event.keyCode] = true;
                }
                // up
                if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    keysPressedDown.current[event.keyCode] = true;
                }
            }, false);
        window.addEventListener("keyup",
            event => {
                // space
                if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                    keysPressedDown.current[event.keyCode] = false;
                }
                if (keysPressedDown.current[32] && event.keyCode == 38 &&
                    keysPressedDown.current[38]) {
                    // call your function here 
                    console.log(' space and up ');
                }
                // up
                if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    keysPressedDown.current[event.keyCode] = false;
                }
            }, false);
    }, []);

    return <></>

}
```